# Expansion of $(a+b)^{1/3}$ with binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

I want to expand $(a+b)^{1/3}$ using the binomial theorem.

1) Is it possible to do that? If not, which expansion should I look up to do so?

2) If yes, how do I evaluate $\dbinom{n}{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi josé, I actually am a complete noob. So please guide me

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks man, will keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) works for non negative integer $n$.

What we can do is use the [binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for

$$(a+b)^{\frac13}=a^\frac13(1+b/a)^\frac13=a^\frac13\left(1+\frac{b}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}+...\right)$$

Comment: then how do you expand {1+(b/a)}^1/3. I think this leads back to the same question. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @KumarAyush take  a look to the link the term $(1+b/a)^\frac13$ can be expanded by binomial series

Comment: what happens if $b>a$ ?

Comment: Ohhhhhh! I get it now man. Thank you so much.

Comment: @KumarAyush Well done! You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @TsemoAristide  I think this always equal to the original equation , till b>0 and -b<a<0.

Comment: @TsemoAristide You are right I didn't mention the convergence condition which requires |b/a|<1. Anyway It is not a problem indeed or |b|<|a| (the case considered) or $|a|<|b|$ (invert a-b) or $|a|=|b|$ in the latter or $a+b=0$ or$ a+b=2a$.

Answer (score 1):

As User GIMUSI already told you, use his method to get a writing of that kind in order to use then:

$$(1 + x)^{\alpha}= \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \binom{\alpha}{k} x^k$$

In your case $\alpha = 1/3$.

Notice that

$$\binom{1/3}{k} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3} - 1\right)\ldots \left(\frac{1}{2} - k + 1\right)}{k!}$$

Thanks to the multiplicative rule.

For example:

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{1/2}n&=\frac{(1/2)^{\underline n}}{n!}\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac12\right)\left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)\dots\left(\frac{2n-3}2\right)}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{2^nn!}\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!(2n-3)!!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n-2)!!(2n-3)!!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n-1}n}\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!^2}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n-1}n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}
\end{align*}$$

Can you procede in a similar way for your case?